# If a download takes more than a certain amount of time it slows down incredibly or stops completely and has to be restarted, why is this?

Tags: networking, internet, downloads, download-speed

I have recently noticed that if I am downloading anything, whether it is an upgrade through `apt`, a file through Firefox or qTox, or basically anything else, if it takes more than from 30 seconds to 2 minutes (it varies between these times) the download will slow down incredibly or stop completely, and it's not like the files are just so huge and I don't have a lot of bandwidth, because I've looked in network monitoring applications and when the downloads slow done incredibly or stop completely there is either a bit of network activity every so often or non at all so it's not even trying to download...

If I restart the downloads they go along as normal unless they take more than that certain amount of time again, and the moment they finish, if another download is scheduled to start immediately afterwards that download works fine as well unless it goes over the time.

I have found this also to the case with all the VMs I run in Virtual Box (I guess because the issue is in the host or a higher level VMs are affected too).

I have other machines on the network, some of which run Ubuntu, and they are having no such problems nor using up all the bandwidth.

I ran a few tests with http://beta.speedtest.net/ and these were the results (though I don't think it ran long enough for it to run into the problems I run into with longer downloads):

[image: Internet speed results]

I'm not such an expert on internet speeds so I don't know if these are good or not, but as I said before, I don't think that tests ran long enough to run into my issues... I also haven't noticed this issue with uploading things, though I haven't uploaded that many things recently.

This issue started about a week ago, so is it something on my machine? Or is this a higher level issue with the ISP or something? But bare in mind that the other machines on my network don't have this same issue and I would think that they would do if it was an ISP or router issue, would they not?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: This doesn't happen to me on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, Lubuntu 14.04 32 or 64 bit, or Lubuntu 15.10 32 bit.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It seems as though I was wrong about it being completely isolated to APT, I have now updated my question.